# Get bouncing rate on Alexa API

Tags: amazon-web-services, seo, alexa-internet

Alexa's web page provides bounce-rate (defined as the percentage of visits to the site that consist of a single pageview). But I can't get the bounce-rate through the API.
Is it possible the API simply doesn't expose it outside?

[I've read [Alexa's API manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/awis-dg-20050711.pdf) , and looked around the web, but no answers].

btw - If you have suggestions for other methods to get bounce rates, I'd appreciate them too!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles here: I ended up using [SimilarWeb's API](https://developer.similarweb.com/)
... It's paid, but it's good!